# Printing a map using ViewsPDF

Tags: 7, views, entities

I am using drupal 7 and the ViewsPDF module to generate PDF's from my content. One of my content types has a map that I have done using a geofield. While trying to export the node as a PDF everything gets printed except the map. I've done a bit of asking around before posting this.
Anyone with a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem with such maps is that, the PDF gets generated before the map appears. 
I'm assuming your map provider is JavaScript based - that means the map appears on the user browser and your server just sets the javascript parameters.

I had to do a similar thing a long time ago, and the only solution that seemed easier was to use Google Maps with static maps. You can embed an image with parameters such as pointer options and geocodes and the maps server will return a static image. Worked in dompdf.

Answer (score 0):

I havent done this, just thinking out load:

Use [hook_views_pre_render()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) to get the view content that should be everything in `#markup` or `#content` value of the Views array that is your Drupal page except the map.

In this hook then try to use php's [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) your page directly into memory. This page may or may not have the map in it actually due to javascript usage on the page. But you should be able to either get a .jpg out of it somehow at this level. Or use a further wget to get an image of the map from the javascript now embedded on the page. You can grab a piece of this page using like [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or a similiar [scraping libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34145/1491507). Once you have the image itself simply alter the view `#content` value to include your image url or image essentially.

This sounds like a huge pain. You'd probably want Cache ([tutorial](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/beginners-guide-caching-data-drupal-7)) this map information using the drupal api and like `cache_set`. You could maybe write all this in like 1 day :). Good luck.